# multiple python packages with the same name

Tags: python, python-3.x, module

I recently started working on an existing project.

This project is composed of several git repositories that may use each other in some hierarchy.
All repositories should be cloned to the same root directory.

Here's an example of the structure:

```
root_dir:
   repo_a:
       module1:
          - a.py
          - b.py
   repo_b:
       module1:
          - c.py
          - d.py
   repo_c:
       module1:
          - e.py
          - f.py
```

Note that I've written "module1" three times on purpose, as it really is the same name.

Now for an example of a file, let's say a.py:

```
from module1.b import foo
from module1.d import goo
from module1.f import zoo

def func():
   foo()
   goo()
   zoo()
```

When trying to run it from the root_dir I'm having trouble, I guess due to the ambiguities and not having relative paths.

Is there a way I can run this project properly without internally changing the code?

Comment: you should be either using `from repo_a.module1.a import foo`

Comment: You might be interested in [namespace packaging](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/packaging-namespace-packages/).

Answer (score 0):

Based on the boundary having to stick with the given structure two ways using importlib:

---

Concise option:

```
from importlib.machinery import SourceFileLoader

repo_a_module1 = SourceFileLoader("module1",">YourSystemPath</repo_a/module1.py").load_module()
repo_b_module1 = SourceFileLoader("module1",">YourSystemPath</repo_b/module1.py").load_module()
repo_c_module1 = SourceFileLoader("module1",">YourSystemPath</repo_c/module1.py").load_module()

repo_a_module1.foo()
repo_b_module1.goo()
repo_c_module1.zoo()
```

---

Another option, but with more code:

```
import importlib.util 
    
repo_a = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location(
  "module1", ">YourSystemPath</repo_a/module1.py")  
repo_a_module1 = importlib.util.module_from_spec(repo_a) 
repo_a.loader.exec_module(repo_a_module1)
    
repo_b = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location(
  "module1", ">YourSystemPath</repo_b/module1.py")  
repo_b_module1 = importlib.util.module_from_spec(repo_b) 
repo_b.loader.exec_module(repo_b_module1)
    
repo_c = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location(
  "module1", ">YourSystemPath</repo_c/module1.py")  
repo_c_module1 = importlib.util.module_from_spec(repo_c) 
repo_c.loader.exec_module(repo_c_module1)
    
    
repo_a_module1.foo()
repo_b_module1.goo()
repo_c_module1.zoo()
```

---

Note: `>YourSystemPath<` can be absolute or relative in both options.

---

Both examples above have a change in the calls of the imported functions (e.g. `foo()` -> `repo_a_module1.foo()` ) which is specific and may help when working with the code later on.

If you have to keep the calls you could add further functions in between:

```
def foo():
    repo_a_module1.foo()

foo()
```